# "Amount" vs. "quantity" in generic?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

It seems like both are used when referring to generic nouns:

```
Product:
    name price amount total
    ---- ----- ------ -----
```

or,

```
Product:
    name price quantity total
    ---- ----- -------- -----
```

So which one should I use?

I've also seen someone use *amount* instead of *total* in case of shares:

```
Shares:
    share price quantity   amount 
    ----- ----- -------- ---------
            *      *     price*qty
```

Should this be correct or not?

Comment: Related: [“Amount” vs. “number” vs. “quantity”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9439/amount-vs-number-vs-quantity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

English divides nouns into *countable* and *uncountable.* Uncontable nouns are those like *sand* and *rain*, where you can't say *three sands* or *three rains* but have to say *three grains of sand* or *three drops of rain*.

You can only use *amount* for uncountable nouns. You can only use *number* for countable nouns. You can use *quantity* for either.

> I have a large amount of sand.
>    I have
>   a large quantity of sand.
>
> I have a large number of chairs.
>    I
>   have a large quantity of chairs.

So if your products can be both uncountable and countable nouns, you should use *quantity*. However, *quantity* sounds wrong if you're talking about money.

I see no advantage to using *amount* rather than *total* for the total cost. You can get away with it when you're talking about shares, since shares are countable, so *amount* cannot refer to shares.  However, if you also have uncountable nouns possible for your products, then people could get the *amount* column and the *quantity* column confused. So I'd recommend using your second example.

Comment: Although it gives no examples for it, the [OALD](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/amount) says **Amount** is also for _countable_.

Comment: Alenanno: Any countable nouns I try to use with *amount* sound wrong. Maybe there are some exceptions, or maybe it's allowed in dialects other than General American.

Comment: @Alenanno: I think the exception (for *amount* and uncountable nouns) has been staring us in the face. Dollars are countable, and *an amount of ten million dollars* sounds perfectly fine to my ear.

Comment: Shor: So you can only use it for money, basically...

Comment: You can certainly use amount for currency and for uncountable nouns. (An amount of 30 dimes would be wrong, but dollars, cents, or pounds would be fine. Shillings only work pre-decimalization.) I can't say for sure that there aren't any other exceptions.

Comment: Peter, that took some time... :D

Answer (score 2):

Let's see the definitions (NOAD):

- **Quantity**: the amount or number of a material or immaterial thing not usually estimated by spatial measurement: `EX: the quantity and quality of the fruit can be controlled.

  EX: note down the sizes, colors, and quantities that you require.`
- **Amount**: a quantity of something, typically the total of a thing or things in number, size, value, or extent.

But for amount the second meaning given is "*a sum of money*", `EX: They have spent a colossal amount rebuilding the stadium.`

Amount can also be a verb, unlike quantity, and it's the following:

> Verb [intrans.] (amount to) **come to be (the total) when added together** : `losses amounted to over 10 million dollars.` [And others side meanings not related with "quantity acception".]

I'd like to note that the two are given as synonyms by the Oxford American Writer's Thesaurus, but it's pretty much obvious that they're not absolute synonyms and therefore are interchangeable in some contexts only.

---

*So considering all of this, if you mean the total of products, I'd use **quantity**, if instead you mean the total of money, I'd use **amount**.*

Answer (score 0):

Amount refers to something which cannot be counted, whereas quantity is used when things can be counted or measured. With a few exceptions, of course, such as money, in which case *amount* is preferred.