# When should I use "amount" as opposed to "number"?

Tags: word-choice

When should I use "amount" as opposed to "number"?

When media are referring to number rather than volume, they often use the word "amount" rather than number, as in "a large amount of people" Is this correct? Is this Preferred? Is this acceptable?

Comment: [Here's](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/amount-vs-number/) [a few](http://grammarist.com/usage/amount-number/) [good](http://www.gingersoftware.com/english-online/spelling-book/confusing-words/amount-number) [sources](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9439/amount-vs-number-vs-quantity). And that last link was even from this site. Links from a simple Google search by the way...

Comment: While not incorrect in it's present form, you're indeed right- _"a large number of people "_ would be the better usage. Just as _amount_ would be better here _a large amount of rain_.

Answer (score 2):

The rule I use is the same is for making the less/fewer distinction: *number* refers to a *discrete* quantity, typically an integer; *amount* refers to a measurable, but uncountable quantity.

So: an *amount* of sand, water, concrete; a *number* of grains of sand, gallons of water, yards of concrete.

If you can have "one" of them, you can have a number of them (or "fewer" of them).

If you need to put it into a container to count it, you have an amount of it (or "less" of it).