# "There is" or "there are"?

Tags: phrases, verbs, grammatical-number, there-is

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“There are so many” vs. “There is so many”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8854/there-are-so-many-vs-there-is-so-many)

I know this is correct:

> There's no problem.

But what if it was plural, i.e. `problems`? Would this be correct, too:

> There **are** no problems.

Or should it be:

> There **is** no problems.

I always wondered about the usage of `there is`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when "problem" is plural you use the plural "are". So, like you said:

> There are no problems

Comment: This is correct (+1), but note that lots of people, when speaking informally do *say* things like "There's no problems" - so don't be surprised if you hear it - but it sounds a bit sloppy so I don't recommend copyig them :)

Comment: Indeed. But when speaking informally people say a lot of things that are wrong... :)

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I've heard it both ways so I've *always* wondered. By the way, Masarah, are you a native speaker? I just want to be sure it's right.

Comment: It is definitely correct. But English is not my mother tongue. But it is my daily language.

Comment: masarah: Yes, that's true, and it's very confusing for a lot of learners - I just wanted to point out that what you say is correct, even if the questioner hears the "wrong" version a lot! @Albus - I am a native speaker and can confirm that what masarah says is true :-)

Comment: @psmears thanks! I'm be a better educated person now. :-D

Answer (score 2):

It should be

> There **are** no **problems**.

"There is no problems" is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The answers given are indeed correct in that they give the correct usage for a plural:

*There is no problem.* (singular)

*There are no problems.* (plural)

However, it is important to note that when one says "There is no problem", the sentence already negates multiple problems. By saying there is no problem, we mean that there is not even one single problem - not one - not any - none at all.

Therefore, the plural "There are no problems" is redundant; even if there were multiple problems and now they have all been cleared up, the singular 'no problem' still covers this.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. You put a fair bit of logic there. I appreciate that.