# "There is people coming" - Game of Thrones last trailer

Tags: grammar

I was wondering why you would say "There is people coming" as you can hear in the last trailer of Game of Thrones. English is not my native language but I'd think that you have to use plural in this sentence such as "There are people coming".

Is this "urban"-talk or am I missing something?

Comment: It's not *"there is people coming"* but *"there's people coming"*.

Comment: thanks.. but what difference does that make? i thought there's == there is

Comment: Who says it? Many of the characters on *Game of Thrones* do not speak what we would call standard English; after all, it's set in a quasi-medieval world with neither universal education nor mass media. See *[“There’s” or “There are”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77089)*, which links to similar questions going back to *[“There are so many” vs. “There is so many”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8854)* (in which see Kosmonaut's answer).

Comment: Though "there's" is obviously a contraction of "there is", it has had its scope extended to stand in for the unpronounceable "there're" in some if not all registers. The French beat us to it: "il y a" can mean "there is" or "there are". But "there is people coming" is a different matter.

Comment: thanks. as peter shor stated out, the stark-girl is actually saying there's. It makes sense to me now. thanks a lot!

Comment: @Edwin: [there're](http://www.forvo.com/word/there%27re/#en) is slightly more pronounceable with an American accent, so some Americans actually use it. But many of us also use *there's* as a contraction for *there are*. I do.