# There IS two different frameworks?

Tags: grammar

> "There’s two different but related frameworks..."

Above is a quote from a Kindle book. How come it is "is" instead of "are"? Isn't it grammarly wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is / there are depends on plurality of the first list element or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not),  ["There are so many" vs. "There is so many"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8854/there-are-so-many-vs-there-is-so-many) etc. There's is used for both 'there is' and 'there are'.

Comment: You're technically correct but you can't really contract "there are" to "there're" so it's not uncommon to use "there's" for "there are" in casual speech.  Which book is the quote from and what is the context?  Dialog?  Technical instructions?  Just curious...  Either way, it's grammatically incorrect but not uncommon.

Comment: There is no such word as *grammarly*. You mean *grammatically*.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez The way expressions are used drives grammaticality. A subset of idioms are the extragrammatical (not ungrammatical) ones such as 'at daggers drawn', 'at sixes and sevens', 'Be seeing you!', 'by and large', 'let alone + noun', 'look daggers at someone', 'of old'. I'd argue that 'There's two ways to look at this' has reached idiom status. 'It's the Smiths' certainly has.

Answer (score 0):

The correct phrase should be

*There are* as explained on Grammarly:

> The choice between the phrases there is and there are at the beginning
>   of a sentence is determined by the noun that follows it. Use there is
>   when the noun is singular (“There is a cat”). Use there are when the
>   noun is plural (“There are two cats”).

-- [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/there-is-there-are/)

Frameworks is plural, so the grammatically correct sentence would be:

> "There are two different but related frameworks..."