# Is "there is no longer enough resources" correct?

Tags: style-manuals

Is "there is no longer enough natural resources to support economic growth" correct?

Should it be There are no longer enough natural resources as verb should agree with noun "resources" which is plural.

Comment: Top result of Google search: http://sana.aalto.fi/awe/grammar/agreement.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["There are so many" vs. "There is so many"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8854/there-are-so-many-vs-there-is-so-many)

Comment: True, it is a duplicate of [*"There are so many" vs. "There is so many"*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8854/there-are-so-many-vs-there-is-so-many). However, that question is a bit of a mess. The accepted answer there is not the [best answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/9248/155553), and the best answer does not use any reputable sources to justify its claim about the acceptability of *there's.* Thus I think it's best to leave this question as is, and provide an answer that uses a reputable source.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, you are right: it should be

[1] ***There are*** no longer enough natural resources to support economic growth.

However, if the style is informal **and** the verb is **cliticized** to the subject, many speakers would use the third person singular:

[2] ***There's*** no longer enough natural resources to support economic growth.

This naturally raises the question of what is the subject in the sentence. Here is [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) (p. 242):

> In the first place, we find variation according to style-level in the present tense. When the copula is cliticised to the subject in informal style, many speakers use the 3rd person singular form irrespective of the number of the post-verbal NP [noun phrase]: <sup>%</sup>*There's only two problems remaining* ['%' indicates that what follows is grammatical in some dialects only]. This pattern suggests the verb agreement is simply with *there,* treated as a 3rd person singular pronoun like it.
>
> When the copula is pronounced as a full independent word, the
>   person-number properties of the verb match those of the post-verbal NP
>   - compare *There **is** **only one problem** remaining* and *There **are** **only two problems** remaining.* Contrasts of this kind appear at first to indicate that the post-verbal NP is subject, but
>   consideration of a wider range of data shows that this is not so.
>   Compare:
>
> [12]  i  *There **tends** to be **a single
>   pre-eminent factor** in the breakup of a marriage.* 
>           ii  *There
>   **tend** to be **several contributing factors** in the breakup of a marriage.*
>
> Ultimately, the choice between the verb-forms *tends* and *tend* is
>   determined by the person-number of the underlined NP, but that NP
>   cannot be the subject of ***tend,*** for it is not located in the
>   ***tend*** clause, but in the ***be*** clause. The situation here is comparable to that found in relative clauses, such as those enclosed
>   in brackets in *the **copy** [which **was** ready]* and *the
>   **copies** [which **were** ready].* The choice between *was* and *were* in the relative clauses depends ultimately on the number of the underlined nominal, which is the antecedent for the relative pronoun
>   *which.* Nevertheless it is *which,* not the antecedent nominal, that is subject of the relative clause. Relative *which* has no inherent
>   person-number properties, but 'inherits* them from its antecedent.
>   Similarly, the dummy pronoun *there* does not have inherent
>   person-number properties but inherits them from the NP that it
>   'displaces* as subject. In [l0ii], *several options* is subject in the
>   canonical version [a] [***Several options*** are open to us], and
>   *there* displaces it as subject in the existential version [b] [*There are **several options** open to us*], taking on its 3rd person plural
>   features. In [12] *there* is subject of the ***tend*** clause, but it
>   is a [raised subject,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_(linguistics)#Examples) and is understood as subject of the ***be*** clause, and it is by virtue of its understood function in that clause that it inherits the person-number features of the underlined NPs. As far as the subject-verb agreement rule is concerned, therefore, it is *there* which counts as subject: the complication is that it inherits its agreement features from the NP it displaces as subject.<sup>21</sup>
>
> <sup><sup>21</sup>A further complication arises in existentials when
>   the verb is followed by an NP-coordination, as in *There was/*were
>   a bottle of wine and several glasses on the table.* *Were* tends to be
>   unidiomatic with an NP-coordination when the coordinate that is
>   adjacent to it is singular, even though the coordination as a whole
>   (*a bottle of wine and several glasses*) is plural. Plural agreement,
>   however, occurs readily in lists: *There are still Brown, Jones, Mason
>   and Smith to interview.*</sup>