# Where is the brakes?

Tags: grammar

Is saying "where **is** the brakes" is correct? I was watching a [video on YouTube](https://youtu.be/-4kzBmmGyhA?t=94) and the guy on it said: *Ow! Where **is** the brakes?*

Comment: Where is the brake ? Meaning the brake pedal. Or if there is only a single brake.Where are the brakes ? if they are in the plural.

Comment: He said _Where's the brakes?_, not _Where is the brakes?_ The former seems more acceptable to me than the latter.

Comment: Where's can only be where is, where has and where does this implying that it is grammatically correct assuming he's referring to where is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "there is no longer enough resources" correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/470538/is-there-is-no-longer-enough-resources-correct)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of "Here's" before a plural noun / noun phrase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/359055/use-of-heres-before-a-plural-noun-noun-phrase) (examples: Here's the details. // Here’s all the ways you can look at this problem. // Here’s some things you should know.) Note that an accurate transcription here is probably  'Where's the brakes'.

Answer (score 1):

No, it would be, **Where are the brakes** as *brakes* are plural. Just for extra clarification, the mistake in the sentence is the usage of *where's* as *where's* can refer to *where is*, *where has* and *where does* and we are safely assuming he means *where is*. It would be much better to say *where're (where are) the brakes* as it is suited to the plural subject.

Comment: Oops my mistake, thank you

Comment: . . . 'brakes' is in the plural. Meaning the word 'brakes' is in the plural.

Comment: Have you watched the video? That's all the proof that you need to the contrary.

Comment: There's a discussion of a similar issue (_there's_ followed by a plural noun) on _Language Log_: https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4519

Comment: I just read through your source and gives a decent explanation as to why this is so.