# A statement with "There are"-- is it grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Is the statement below grammatically correct?

> "There are a cupboard, a tea table, and a carpet."

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["There are so many" vs. "There is so many"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8854/there-are-so-many-vs-there-is-so-many) (see Kosmonaut's answer, re [There is/are + nominal]: agreement with number, but with 'there's + plural noun' becoming acceptable in informal English).

Comment: grammar has two m's in English.

Comment: Welcome  to EL&U. Please note that general requests for proofreading—"Is this correct?" or "Can this be worded better?"— are not permitted here, as they do not work well with the Stack Exchange Q&A model. We can help you work through *specific* points of grammar or usage which may confuse you, however. I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help]. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may also be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Exception at the bottom of:
[grammar link](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_v&page=9SC4lWsaAlSw.html)

both

> "There **are** a cupboard, a tea table, and a carpet."

and

> "There **is** a cupboard, a tea table, and a carpet."

are correct. With the latter being preferred due to sounding more natural.